# Sending a user to a VoIP call if they have VoIP and elsewhere if they do not

Tags: php, html, redirect

I have a webpage that sends a user to a VoIP call:

```
<li <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['UserData'])){ ?> style="border-right: 1px solid #e6e6e6;" <?php } ?>><a href="tell:8776983355"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>Phone: 1.877.698.3355</a></li>
```

My concern is that if the user does not have VoIP the address it is sent to will be `Address not understood` and the webpage will error out. Is there a way I could send the user to a different page such as a `Contact Us` page if the address is not understood? IE:

```
<li <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['UserData'])){ ?> style="border-right: 1px solid #e6e6e6;" <?php } ?>><a href=<?php try { echo "tell:5248975465"; } catch (Exception $e) { echo "contactus.php"; } ?>><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>Phone: 1.877.698.3355</a></li>
```

This way when people who have the correct VoIP info will automatically dial and people who do not have the VoIP info will be sent to a contact page containing our information. Is this possible?

Comment: Wouldn't you need a way to check the system to see if VoIP is enabled? If so, I don't think native PHP has anything like that available.

Comment: I'd technically just need to check the browser to see if the address would be understood by it or not